# Можно ли как-то ещё ускорить данный код?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, логика

```
sort(subset2.begin(), subset2.end());
long long int v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < subset1.size(); i++)
    v += upper_bound(subset2.begin(), subset2.end(), (k - subset1[i])) - subset2.begin();
```

Где subset1 и subset2 - это вектора подмножеств первой и второй половины множества соответственно.

Их я находил таким образом:

```
subset1.resize(1 << (vect1.size()));
for (int i = 1; i < (1 << vect1.size()); i++)
    subset1[i] = subset1[i & (i - 1)] + vect1[__builtin_ctz(i)];
```

Comment: А можно узнать исходную стоящую перед вами задачу?

Comment: @Harry не узнаёте код?) Метод Meet-in-the-midle для задачи рюкзака

Comment: @pavel Нет, я не настолько крут и всезнающ :)

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t size1 = 1 << (vect1.size());
subset1.resize(size1);
for (int i = 1; i < size1; i++)
    subset1[i] = subset1[i & (i - 1)] + vect1[__builtin_ctz(i)];

sort(subset2.begin(), subset2.end());
long long int v = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
  ...
```

Вы каждый раз считаете результат одного и того же выражения, а нужно считать один раз и сохранить его в каком то обьекте.
  Подозреваю: что вместо вектора лучше  подойдет `multiset`.

Comment: что простите? Как тут использовать set? и какое выражение несколько раз считается

Comment: Речь шла не об ошибке в программе, а об возможной оптимизации

Comment: subset1.size()  вызывается subset1.size() раз в цикле,  и выражение  (1 << vect1.size()) считается столько же раз в другом цикле, а до этого еще и  в методе   resize

Comment: ошибка у вас явно присутствует  в   upper_bound(subset2.begin(), subset2.end(), (k - subset1[i])) - subset2.begin(); Но я какраз говорил не об ошибке, а об оптимизации...  Вот почему мне перестало нравится отвечать  тут - вместо спасибо получаешь упреки

Comment: я понял, но замена `i < subset1.size()` на сохранение в переменную вроде бы ничего не даёт. А вот по поводу бинарного поиска - выглядит правильно.

Comment: @Melliodas вроде бы сильно тут ничего не изменить. А зачем вам это понадобилось? P.S. тут по сути мой код в вопросе.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan прошу прощения за свой комментарий выше, но похоже что между нами произошло недарузомение. Я никаким образом не хотел вас обидеть, а просто уточнить так как не очень понял ваш ответ из-за своего маленького опыта в языке.

Comment: @pavel я просто прошелся по данным тестам и 4 из 50 не прошли по времени (но время алгоритма ведь O(2^(N/2)) ?)

Comment: @Melliodas можете попробовать отсортировать оба массива и вместо бинарного поиска делать скользящее окно.